# Passing data between classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have developed a quiz game and everything works really well but there is a thing I want to improve:
My problem is that I have 3 View Controllers. In the first View Controller the user selects single or multiplayer modus.

The second ViewController is the quiz game. 
But now in the third ViewController (the result screen) I need to know if the user chose single or multiplayer modus.

I don't know how to pass this boolean from ViewController 1 to ViewController 3.

At the moment I have a boolean in every ViewController and just pass this variable from View1 to View2 and then to View3. But I don't like this solution. Is there a way that I solve this with delegates? Or do you know any other, better solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you like you can use appdelgate to solve this problem

Comment: @AalokParikh How can I use app delegate for this?

Comment: Just declare one ivar in appdelegate and then using appdelegate's variable you can do this like assign this variable in VC1 and in VC3 access it.

Comment: Need code for that then ask for it I will give it to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model-View-Controller approach suggests that the boolean value belongs in the Model code of your application. It is a common thing to make your model a *singleton*:

QuizModel.h

```
@interface QuizModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL isMultiplayer;
-(id)init;
+(QuizModel*)instance;
@end
```

QuizModel.m

```
static QuizModel* inst = nil;

@implementation QuizModel
@synthesize isMultiplayer;
-(id)init {
    if(self=[super init]) {
        self.isMultiplayer = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
+(QuizModel*)instance {
    if (!inst) inst = [[QuizModel alloc] init];
    return inst;
}
@end
```

Now you can use the boolean in your controller code: include `"QuizModel.h"`, and write

```
if ([QuizModel instance].isMultiplayer)
```

or

```
[QuizModel instance].isMultiplayer = YES;
```

Comment: Perfekt solution! Does exactly what I wanted to do. thanks! I'm interested in this topic cause it's really basic so are there any other possibilities to do this?